# Failed to Run Flex Unit Tests using ANT Build - Error while loading initial content

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex4, automation

I am using a sample Flex AIR Application to Automate my Flex Unit Tests and Run them using Continuous Integration ANT BUILD. But when I run the ANT Build i am facing the below errors. Here is my console Error.

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\build.xml
build:
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\deploy
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\report
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\deploy
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\report
setup:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\deploy
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\deploy\snapshots
compile:
     [java] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\air-config.xml
     [java] C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\deploy\TwitterClient.swf (5691817 bytes)
execute_tests:
 [flexunit] Validating task attributes ...
 [flexunit] Generating default values ...
 [flexunit] Using default working dir [C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI]
 [flexunit] Using the following settings for the test run:
 [flexunit]     FLEX_HOME: [C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0]
 [flexunit]     haltonfailure: [false]
 [flexunit]     headless: [false]
 [flexunit]     display: [99]
 [flexunit]     localTrusted: [true]
 [flexunit]     player: [air]
 [flexunit]     port: [1024]
 [flexunit]     swf: [null]
 [flexunit]     timeout: [60000ms]
 [flexunit]     toDir: [C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\report]
 [flexunit] Setting up server process ...
 [flexunit] Starting server ...
 [flexunit] Opening server socket on port [1024].
 [flexunit] Waiting for client connection ...
 [flexunit] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\\bin\adl.exe' with arguments:
 [flexunit] 'C:\Users\akishore\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TwitterClient-CI\deploy\TwitterClient-app.xml'
 [flexunit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [flexunit] not part of the command.
 [flexunit] error while loading initial content
```

Comment: The error seems to say you're having some quoting issues in your arguments.

Comment: I've seen this "error while loading initial content" message when there is a mismatch between your AIR SDK version and the namespace in the app's XML file as shown [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=error%20while%20loading%20initial%20content&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.sunild.com%2F2008%2F12%2Ferror-while-loading-initial-content.html&ei=fGflUMntOcm0igK6r4DIBw&usg=AFQjCNHsLYie7X7938r0cSMQXoDM3tLuHA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.cGE). In this case that XML file is associated with your test runner app ...

Comment: Not sure how to correct it in this case, as I'm assuming that file is auto generated.